# Weird parsing of anchor tag within AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm making an `AJAX` call to my service as below and I am getting the response which I'm displaying it in a table by inserting some `HTML` into the success callback. All works fine and I have no issue. Code added below.

The `AJAX` call

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:56083/Service1.svc/Web/GetAll',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: 'false',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#log-Details').data("respData", data);
            cache[cacheValue] = data;
            console.log(cache[cacheValue]);
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                var IntId = value.IntegrationId;
                var Status = value.Status;
                changeStatusCSS(Status);
                $('<tr><td>' + icon + '<a style="' + cssClass + '" id="row' + IntId + '" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Integration")">#' + IntId + '</a></td><td>'
                    + Status + '</td>').appendTo('#log-Details');

            });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        }
    })
```

The inner `HTML` for `<tr>` parsed by the browser as below

```
<td>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" style="color:#007A24"></span>
  <a style="color:#007A24" id="row1" href="/Integration/Details">#1</a>
</td>
<td>Success</td>
```

However, I decided to write a generic method for the `AJAX` call since I needed to reuse the `AJAX` call format quite often. So I changed the the code as below and added a separate method for the success callback.

```
function getPagedResult(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response){
            OnSuccess(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        var IntId = value.IntegrationId;
        var Status = value.Status;
        changeStatusCSS(Status);
        $('<tr><td>' + icon + '<a style="' + cssClass + '" id="row' + IntId + '" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Integration")">#' + IntId + '</a></td><td>'
                       + Status + '</td>').appendTo('#log-Details');

    });
}
```

As you can see there's no difference in both the success callbacks since all I did was copy from the previous code section and paste it into this method. However, this time the browser parses the innerHTML as below for some unknown reason which results in an error on the click of the anchor tag. The URl formed goes something like "**http.../Integration/@Url.Action(**". Struggling to figure out the reason behind this change in behaviour.

```
<td>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="color:#337ab7"></span>
  <a style="color:#337ab7" id="row5" href="@Url.Action(" details ",=" " "integration ")"="">#5</a>
</td>
<td>InProgress</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dynamically adding elements using javascript, `@Url.Action("Details", "Integration")` is not recommended because that's serverside language.

On Client Side , `"/Integration/Details"` is valueable.

Use

```
'" href="/Integration/Details">#'
```

instead of

```
'" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Integration")">#'
```

Comment: What you mean to say is that it is not escaping the function correctly.

Comment: @artgb Fair enough! I am just wondering as to why it would work in the first scenario if that's the case..